# how to implement a outlook like calendar in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

i wannt to implement an calender application in qt, should look like http://outlookhelptech.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Outlook-calendar-1.png.

How would you implement something like this in qt.

So the two main questions are:

1.) is there a view / widget calender which supports weekly view, monthly view

2.) but more important is how to implement the visualization of the tasks per day like in the picture above?

Is it easier to implement it in qt5 (qml)?

Comment: Hey! I'm working on something like this on my free-from-work time. Could you email me? We might union efforts if we had the same goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own widget, based on [QGraphicsScene](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsscene.html). Such controls are to specific and too hard, so there is no free versions, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready view in Qt which would handle this kind of data.
This is not a table neither a list or tree, so item model view available in Qt will not work well here.

You should look for some external library. For example KDE have an application  [KOrganizer](http://www.kde.org/applications/office/korganizer/). KDE is Qt based so taking a pick on this project is a good idea.